# Trying to use Python to clean up null/bad data in Lat/Lon Load

Tags: arcgis-desktop, field-calculator, python-parser

[image: Failed Code]

I'm using `ArcMap` 10.4.  Trying to load a list of Lat/Lons and connect the surface hole and bottom holes with a line connector (`Toolbox XY to Line`).  I have two issues:

1) Values which have BHL and no SHL.  I took care of those with a definition query `Surf_Lat >0` in the data table which just doesn't plot the wells which don't have a surface hole.

2) Values which are from vertical wells and have a BHL `Lon = 0` and BHL `Lat = 0`.  What I need to do is make the `BHL = SHL` if the values are zero.  I've not been successful in trying to do a definition query because I can't figure out how to do the statement from (1) above, and also do an IF statement.

I need to fix this somehow as you can see in the background I have lines going crazy on the map trying to "connect" to this 0 Latitude value. I've taken some Python classes but not sure about assigning the name of the value here in my equation.

Code

```
def mycalc(Surf_Lon, Surf_Lat):
    if (Surf_Lon=0):
      return mycalc=Surf_Lat
    else:
     return mycalc=Surf_Lon
```

Comment: Also note that in Python `if x=0` will actually set x to equal 0. You need to use the double-equals operator `if x==0` to test equivalence - see [Built-in Types Comparison](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#comparisons)

Comment: I changed to <1 rather than zero in the equation.  I'm still having execution issues (as posted below) with error message Expected 'Then' and not sure what that error means.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the "Show Codeblock" above where you have your function. Put the function in the codeblock, then call on it in the window where it is now. Also, you have to be careful about the indentation to make sure it is consistent; use 4 spaces at a time for indenting.

It looks like you're trying to replace the value if the borehole value is 0... If you're doing this for each field individually (one for lat and one for lon) you might want to use a function that is more generic, like

```
def replaceZeroVal(input, replaceWith):
    if input == 0 OR input is None:
        return replaceWith
```

Then when you call on it in the field calculator (for bhl_lat) with

```
replaceZeroVal(bhl_lat, surface_lat)
```

EDIT:

[image]

I know my schema doesn't match yours, but the field calculator window should be set up like this.

Comment: I agree your code is much easier.  So, just tried it.  Will not run.  Keeps returning the error Expected 'Then'. I thought it had to do with needing an else statement in there and tried that and didn't help.  I tried to find this error message online and was having trouble.

Comment: I bet you have the VB Script Parser checked in the top of the window; check the Python parser box and try it. Python doesn't have a "Then" for if statements, but VB does

Answer (score 1):

```
def replaceZeroVal(input, replaceWith):
    if input <1:
      return replaceWith
    else:
      return input

replaceZeroVal(!Bot_Lat!, !Surf_Lat!)
```

Okay, the issue is in the bottom needs to have the exclamation points to say it is calling data specifically from the data table.  I found this through GeoNet.